# .Net (Xamarin) Shared library works in Android but not iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, shared-libraries, restsharp

We have a solution with an Android project, and iOS project and a shared library. The shared library has RestSharp installed (v 106.3.1).

When we run the Android app it works fine, it uses the shared library, it uses RestSharp to connect to a server and get some info.

When we run the iOS app (it builds fine) it stops mid execution and gives us this error:

Unhandled Exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'MyLibrary.ItemManager+<>c__DisplayClass4_0:client' (0) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75' or one of its dependencies. assembly:RestSharp, Version=106.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75 type: member:(null) signature: occurred

We've done some research and tried closing and opening VS, reinstalling RestSharp, check references, etc. But it works with the Android project so it would seem to be set up correctly.

Any help?

Comment: In the case of iOS, many times you must included the DLL in the iOS project as well so that when built it has all necessary files. This is pretty common for iOS, whereas like you said Android doe snot suffer from this issue.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I had though about that but I couldn't find the rest sharp dll file in the shared library folder. Turns out it was in another folder called packages outside of the projects.

Comment: Glad that took care of it for you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xamarin iOS projects you need to include the DLL's and/or Nuget packages in the iOS project itself, as the compiler does not perform those actions for you.